# cosine_sim between a text and a single column in a dataset

Tags: python, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

i have a dataset that i have to do lemmarization for it which i did below then i have to find similarity between 1 column "text " with the word " vaccine is deadly" but not sure how to use the cosine similarity function right i tried putting the text in a value and do it but its not working ,,

```
texttweet2 = pd.read_csv("../input/pfizer-vaccine-tweets/vaccination_tweets.csv")

wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
def tokenize(str_input):    
words = re.sub(r"(?u)[^A-Za-z]", " ", str_input).lower().split(" ")
words = [stemmer.stem(word) for word in words if len(word)>2]
words = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in words if len(word)>2]
return words


vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english')
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(texttweet2['text'])
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
texttweet_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(vectors.toarray(),columns=feature_names)
```

---

my attempt to do the cosine similarity

```
x= "vaccine is deadly"


cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(x, texttweet_tfidf)
```

but im getting this error :
could not convert string to float: 'vaccine is deadly'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cosine_similarity` takes in vectors of numbers, and not strings. You will need to use the vectorizer to convert the string into a vector.

```
x = "vaccine is deadly"
x_vector = vectorizer.transform([x])
x_tfidf = pd.DataFrame(vectors.toarray(), columns=feature_names)

cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(x_tfidf, texttweet_tfidf)
```